# How to wire G9 socket base?

Tags: wiring, lamp, socket

I'm trying to replace broken lamp part, but have no idea how to wire G9 ceramic socket base like presented below. How to attach wires inside these little holes? Is there some additional parts - plugs maybe?

[image: G9 Ceramic Socket Base]

Answer (score 3):

The pairs of holes labelled "L" and "N" probably contain "stab" or push-fit connectors.

Try pushing a stripped wire into one of each and test.

Comment: If they are push-fit, stranded wire will not work in them and would have to be tinned with solder first to make it stiff.

Comment: @JPhi1618 probably better to use a crimp ferrule than tinning

Answer (score 3):

From the picture it looks like the ones I just replaced.  They were push-fit and I was able to get the stranded wire to work without tinning by twisting up the strands very tight.

btw.  Through trial and error, I figured out that releasing the wires is done by pushing a small screwdriver in from the bulb side.  Sorry, I don't have a picture.